# Jolt Transform results null in the Output-File

Tags: json, file-io, null, jolt

I have following Input-File, which I want to convert into the Output-File below. But the Output-file results null.

**Input**:

```json
{
  "edinachraz_such": "ABAS_TO_OPERATIONS1",
  "id": "(462793,53,0)",
  "fcode": 0,
  "status": 2,
  "table": [
    {
      "zn": 1,
      "text3": "Kommentar",
      "text4": "20.01.2021",
      "text1": "Maintenance of machine BCX 7712",
      "text2": "Check oil pressure , oil leck",
      "text7": "abc",
      "text5": "23.01.2021",
      "text6": "[2133]"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Jolt Spec**:

```json
[
 {
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "table": {
      "text1": "name",
      "text2": "description",
      "text3": "comments",
      "text4": "startDate",
      "text5": "dueDate",
      "text6": "documentBaseIds",
      "text7": "classification"
    }
  }
 }
]
```

**Expected Output**:

```json
{
 "name ": "Maintenance of machine BCX 7712",
 "description": "Check oil pressure , oil level",
 "comments ": "User comments",
 "startDate ": "utc",
 "dueDate ": "tuc",
 "documentBaseIds " : [2133],
 "classification " : tbd
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add `"*": {` following `"table": {` to represent indexes of the `table` array, in order to be able to walk through the elements of it such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "table": {
        "*": {
          "text1": "name",
          "text2": "description",
          "text3": "comments",
          "text4": "startDate",
          "text5": "dueDate",
          "text6": "documentBaseIds",
          "text7": "classification"
        }
      }
    }
 }
]
```

[image]